# espruino: wifi on connect event not fired

Tags: javascript, esp8266, espruino

I need to be notified when the ESP8266 get connected to the WiFi network.
To do so I'm listening to the `connected` event in the WiFi module.
The callback function is never called.

The code:

```
var wifi = require("Wifi");

wifi.on('connected', function(details) { 
  console.log('connected to wifi', details);
});

wifi.connect("*****", {password:"****"}, function(err){
    console.log("connected? err=", err, "info=", wifi.getIP());
});
```

The output:

```
>
=undefined
connected? err= null info= {
  "ip": "192.168.1.105",
  "netmask": "255.255.255.0",
  "gw": "192.168.1.1",
  "mac": "5c:**:7f:**:7a:**"
 }
```

Comment: And if you put the `wifi.on('connected'` below the `connect`?

Comment: Same result, callback not called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event is not fired because the ESP8266 was already connected to the WiFi network. When you setup your connection you can [save](https://www.espruino.com/Reference#t_l_Wifi_save) the settings in order to get Espruino reconnect to the WiFi automatically at boot time.